Ubuntu repository version of libpango1.0-dev depends on non-Ubuntu versions of packages
I'm trying to install libpango1.0-dev (in order to then install librealsense2-utils). When I run apt-cache policy libpango1.0-dev, I get:
libpango1.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.50.6+ds-2
  Version table:
     1.50.6+ds-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages

Indicating that the package is available from the official Ubuntu repositories.
When I then run sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev, I get this:
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpango1.0-dev : Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (= 1.50.6+ds-2) but 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (= 1.50.6+ds-2) but 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (= 1.50.6+ds-2) but 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (= 1.50.6+ds-2) but 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libpangoxft-1.0-0 (= 1.50.6+ds-2) but 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: pango1.0-tools (= 1.50.6+ds-2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

If I read this correctly, the version of libpango1.0-dev that I am trying to install depends on the "generic" versions of several libraries, but the only versions available for my system are Ubuntu-specific versions.
Am I interpreting this correctly? If so, doesn't that make this version incompatible with my system? Why would this version of libpango1.0-dev be available from the official Ubuntu repo?
A coworker of mine with the same issue decided to try to replace those 6 packages with the required versions. The result was a thoroughly broken system and a reinstall of the OS.
Details:

OS is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
No packages are held
I ran apt update and apt upgrade before doing anything. Both completed without errors.


Check your apt sources. Your jammy-updates repository seems to be missing.

You are entirely correct. For the benefit of my future self, how did you know, and what is the significance of that?

Your package shows you've not applied updates; ie. your apt policy should have showed libpango1.0-dev | 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 | jammy-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x which would mean that package could be out of date and not match other newer installed packages for jammy.   Your package was from install media (2024-April) and had NOT updated since then   (FYI:  I did a CLI enquiry on packages available; ie. rmadison libpango1.0-dev but detail can be obtained in many ways)

@guiverc is right, that's how I got there too. It's probably not a skill you need, but since you asked...The first thing I check in a "you have requested an impossible situation" is the apt sources. I use the rmadison script (from the devscripts package) to check that the version of libpango1.0-dev show current Ubuntu package versions. The next step would have been to have you show us your complete apt update output to see if any common repos were missing (like jammy-updates), but you already provided policy output with enough information. Kudos for providing policy output.
